# if-unless gives the same retun in thymeleaf engine

Tags: spring-boot, if-statement, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am trying to perfom an if statement in thymeleaf engine for one of the properties of an objects in a List.

My purpose is if **somoLetu.hSecondReading == null** I should see a text of **No Second Reading**,but if not I should see **Second Reading**. But The output displays **Second Reading** text in both scenarios either null or not, What Am i doing wrong.

Here is how I do it in thymeleaf in **masomo.html** file

```
        <div th:each="somoLetu : ${masomoYote}" class="container my-5">

        <h1 th:text= "${somoLetu.date}"></h1>
        <h1 th:text= "${somoLetu.familiaName}"></h1>
        <h1 th:text= "${somoLetu.kanda}"></h1>
  
        <div th:if= "${somoLetu.hSecondReading == null}" ><h1>No Second Reading</h1></div>
        <div th:unless= "${somoLetu.hSecondReading == null}" ><h1>Second Reading</h1>  <h1 th:text="${somoLetu.hSecondReading}"></h1></div>
       </div>
        </div>
```

These are the properties of my object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "misale")
public class Misale {

                      
   @Id
   @Column(name ="date")
   private String date;
   @Column(name ="h_second_reading")
   private String hSecondReading; 
   private String familiaName;
   private String kanda;
   
    .................}
```

This is my method in Controller class to get all the list

```
@Autowired
 private MisaleRepository misaleRepository;
 @GetMapping("/masomo")
    public String masomoAngalia(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("masomoYote", misaleRepository.findAll() );
   
        return "masomo";
    
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `hSecondReading`? Are you sure it is `null` and not an empty string? Those are not the same thing. Maybe use Thymeleaf's `isEmpty`helper: `${#strings.isEmpty(somoLetu.hSecondReading)}`

Comment: Wow,, I have tried the thymeleaf's **isEmpty** helper: **${#strings.isEmpty(somoLetu.hSecondReading)}** as suggested and it is working fine.Thank you soo much  @RoToRa

Comment: @RoToRa post that as an answer so that I can accept it.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value of `hSecondReading`? Are you sure it is `null` and not an empty string? Those are not the same thing.

You should be aware whether a variable is (or can be) null or not. This can lead to more serious errors in Java, if you don't pay attention to that.

Maybe use Thymeleaf's `isEmpty` helper: `${#strings.isEmpty(somoLetu.hSecondReading)}`